# Additional information stored in object

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 2 application I've got a class **Guide** :

```
export class Guide{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

When I store data in an object of this class, Angular creates more variables, depending of the response.
If I get a response like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Guide",
    "created_at": "2016-11-04T08:50:39+0000"
}
```

then my object of type `Guide` has also the variable "created_at" with the value of "created_at".

How can I just store the two variables `id` and `name` in my object?

Comment: This is what happens when you `JSON.parse`. Typing has nothing to do with runtime behavior. Just delete if it's a problem. Or just ignore it

Comment: I don't use `JSON.parse`. I use: `this.guideService.getGuide().subscribe(guide => {
            this.guide = guide;
        });`

Comment: Somewhere, it is being used. Probably by Angular `res.json()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but how can I set the guide without using `res.json()`?

Comment: Forget about that. Just delete the properties if it's really a problem. This doesn't work like other typed languages where you can parse JSON  with a library, and whatever the properties the class has, that's all it will get from the JSON. Javascript is dynamic, so when parsing JSON, properties just get added dynamically. There's no way around that. The type `Guide` is only good at compile-time. At runtime, There's no such thing as typing. So JS just parses to a normal JS object

Comment: Not an answer to the question. But nevertheless: Consider using `interface` instead of `class` for plain objects like `Guide` and others that contain no real state and don't user inheritance. This enables you to use object literals for instances of this type. And it's actually more what `JSON.parse()` returns you, since this won't set a constructor and prototype chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.guide = guide;
```

Is overwriting your object with a new object guide it is not casting it that is why you are getting additional values. Objects work by reference and you are overwriting the reference.

If you are using typescript try something like:

```
this.guide = <Guide>guide;
```

Although i am not sure this will eliminate the other values.

The other alternative is that you need to build a constructor onto Guide object

```
export class Guide{
  constructor(object:any)
  {
    this.id = object.id;
    this.number = object.number;
  }

   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

then you call it like this

```
this.guide = new Guide(guide);
```

Comment: `this.guide = <Guide>guide;` will not remove any properties, since it's the same at runtime than the version without the type cast. Your other version would work. Or simply copy all known properties of the object instead of creating a new one for each event. Like `this.guide.id = guide.id; this.guide.number = guide.number;` This could also be encapsulates inside a function.

Comment: yeah thats what i thought. constructor is nicer because you do it once and you can put your parse logic in there once.